# How do I write a simple string to a file on the iphone?

Tags: iphone

Simple question:

I have a large string that I want to write to a file in the docs folder for an app.  How do I do a simple file creation/write?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have an `NSString`, you can do

```
NSString *myString; //Assuume the string you want to write is this
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];
[myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Method is deprecated, use [myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; instead!

Answer (score 9):

Look at `NSString`'s `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method.  Usage looks like this:

```
[myString writeToFile:myPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&myError];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSError *error = nil;
[@"foo bar baz" writeToFile:@"someFileName" atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```